# Translate svg element so data lines up with axes

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to modify an example scatterplot [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118) to include gridlines and also to functionize the plotting like I've seen in tutorial I'm taking. I am able to add the gridlines and create a plot function, but the data points no longer line up with the axes.

Question: How can I make the data and the axes align?

[image]

I think the problem is with how the SVG element is translated or something with the "chart" class. I've tried various translations using the height and width vars, but still don't understand how to make my gridlines and data match up without manually translating things until they fit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Place all DOM elements here -->
<script>
var w = 800;
var h = 450;
var margin = {
    top: 60,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 100,
    right: 80
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


var chart = svg.append("g")
    .classed("display", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var yGridlines = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSize(-width,0,0)
    .tickFormat("")
    .orient("left");

var xGridlines = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    //.tickValues(tickValues)
    .tickSize(-height,-height)
    .tickFormat("")
    .orient("bottom");

function drawAxis(params){
    if(params.initialize){
        this.append("g")
            .classed("gridline x", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(params.axis.gridlines.x);
        this.append("g")
            .classed("gridline y", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(params.axis.gridlines.y);
        this.append("g")
            .classed("axis x", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(params.axis.x);
        this.append("g")
            .classed("axis y", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(params.axis.y);
        this.select(".y.axis")
            .append("text")
            .classed("y axis-label", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + -56 + "," + height/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
            .text("Sepal Length")
        this.select(".x.axis")
            .append("text")
            .classed("x axis-label", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + 48 + ")")
            .text("Sepal Width");
        this.append("g")
            .append("text")
            .classed("chart-header", true)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-24)")
            .text("");
    }
}

function plot(params){
  params.data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(params.data, function(d) { return d.sepalWidth; }))
  y.domain(d3.extent(params.data, function(d) { return d.sepalLength; }))

  drawAxis.call(this, params);

  /*
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sepal Width (cm)");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sepal Length (cm)")
      */

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(params.data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.sepalWidth); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sepalLength); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + ((i * 20) + 100) + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 40)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 44)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });


};

d3.csv("iris.csv", function(error, parsed_data) {
    plot.call(chart, {
        data: parsed_data,
        axis: {
            x: xAxis,
            y: yAxis,
            gridlines:{
                x: xGridlines,
                y: yGridlines
            }
        },
        initialize: true
    })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note: the data is on the example I liked to. Here's a sample for reproducibility:

```
// Data in either csv or tsv depending on preference:
sepalLength sepalWidth  petalLength petalWidth  species
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
4.9 3   1.4 0.2 setosa
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5   3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6.4 3.2 4.5 1.5 versicolor
6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5 versicolor
5.5 2.3 4   1.3 versicolor
6.5 2.8 4.6 1.5 versicolor
6.5 3   5.5 1.8 virginica
7.7 3.8 6.7 2.2 virginica
7.7 2.6 6.9 2.3 virginica
6   2.2 5   1.5 virginica
6.9 3.2 5.7 2.3 virginica
```

Comment: You're appending the axes to `chart` and the circles to `svg` -- try appending to the same element (`chart`).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I changed  ```svg.selectAll(".dot")``` to  ```chart.selectAll(".dot")```and everything lines up now! Was that all you meant, or is there a better general structure that would be better?